# $f(x+1)= {3x+5 \over 2x+1}, x\neq-1/2, f(x)=?$

Tags: recreational-mathematics

$f(x+1)= {3x+5 \over 2x+1}, x\neq-1/2$

How can I get f(x)?

More generally, if I have $f(x+k)$ what do I have to do to get $f(x)$

Comment: *Hint:* $3x+5 = 3x+3+2 = 3(x+1)+2$

Answer (score 3):

You can get it easily applying the equality with $x-1$.

$$
f(x)=f((x-1)+1) = \dfrac{3(x-1)+6}{2(x-1)+1}
$$

More generally,

$$
f(x) = f((x-k)+k)
$$